# codemod/transform include BlockStatement

Tags: javascript, abstract-syntax-tree, jstransform, jscodeshift

I'm doing a *codemod*/*transform* to change `if`/`return` statements in my code.

I have a lot of `if(err) do something` and I need to refactor that behavior.

How can I make a transform for this?

What I have:

```
if (err) {
  return connection.rollback(function() {
    throw err;
  });
}
```

What I want:

```
if (err){
    return rollback(connection, err);
}
```

I managed so far to replace the `node.consequent` and use a `callExpression` directly:

```
root.find(j.IfStatement).replaceWith(function (_if) {
  var fnCall = j.callExpression(j.identifier('rollback'), [
    j.identifier('connection'), 
    j.identifier('err')
  ]);

  _if.node.consequent = fnCall; 
  return _if.node;
});
```

...resulting in:

```
if (err)
  rollback(connection, err);
```

How to also include the `BlockStatement` and a `return` inside it? is this the correct way to do this *codemod*?

#### live example [here](http://felix-kling.de/esprima_ast_explorer/#/MYgEORhNkq)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, made it! What a nice tool!

> please do comment or post a new answer if there is a better way to do this!

So, what i was missing was both a block statement `{}` in the `if` statement, and inside it a `return`.

So I added:

```
var ret = j.returnStatement(fnCall);
var block = j.blockStatement([ret]);
_if.node.consequent = block;
```

result here: http://astexplorer.net/#/84e8ZqEAwQ/1

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it can look like using [putout](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout) code transformer:

```js
const from = `
    if (err) {
      return connection.rollback(function() {
        throw err;
      });
    }
`;

const to = `
    if (err){
        return rollback(connection, err);
    }
`;

export const replace = () => ({
    [from]: to
});
```

`Putout` converts `from` into `AST`, searches similar parts and replace them with a `to` `AST`. All this stuff works without a need of touching `AST` itself from consumer.

[image: Putout Editor]